# Android ResponseListener JSON Error when trying to initialize JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am developing an app that will be storing to and reading data from `MySQL` db. At the moment I am able to successfully fetch `1 row` but when I am trying to fetch `multiple rows` it doesn't work. The code breaks when I try to initialize `JSONObject`(I put a comment above the line that gives the `error`) in the `ResponseListener`. To communicate with my db I am using the volley library.

Here is the error output:

```
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.www.myapp.DataActivity$2.onResponse(DataActivity.java:235)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.www.myapp.DataActivity$2.onResponse(DataActivity.java:229)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
08-23 17:27:12.853 22689-22689/com.example.www.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my code so far:

**Response Listener**

```
private void getDataFromExternalDB(final String startid){
        id = Integer.parseInt(startid);
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    //I get the error at the following line
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    while (jsonResponse.getJSONObject(""+id) != null){
                       jsonResponse.getJSONObject(""+id);
                        int user_id = jsonResponse.getInt("user_id");
                        String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");

                        Log.d("getDataFromExternalDB","user_id="+user_id + " username="+username);

                        id++;
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        DataRequest dataRequest = new DataRequest (startid, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DataActivity.this);
        queue.add(dataRequest );
}
```

**DataRequest.java**

```
 import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String DATA_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.178.17/getData.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public DataRequest (String startid, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, DATA_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("startid", startid);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**getData.php**

```
 <?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "db");

    $startid = $_POST["startid"];   

    function getData() {
        global $connect, $startid;
        $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > " . $startid );
        $responses = array();
        $response = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $response["user_id"] = $row["user_id"]; 
                $response["username"] = $row["username"];


                $responses["" . $row["user_id"]]=$response;
            }
            echo json_encode($responses);
        }else {
            echo "0 results";
        } 

    }

    getData();  

    $connect->close();  

?>
```

Comment: Can you paste a printout of the response before you try and cast it to json?

Comment: @MichaelStoddart `echo responses["number here"]["username"] ; `

And it returns the username.

Comment: Post the string on the Java side:  `public void onResponse(String response)` before the new JSONObject() creation.

Comment: In the on response method put this code: System.out.println("RESPONSE >>> " + response); so we can see what is returned from your server

Comment: @MichaelStoddart this is the code I added to test whats in `response` - 
               `if(!response.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE>>"+response);
                    Log.d("getDataFromExternalDB","response="+response);
                    Log.d("getDataFromExternalDB","entered onResponse if");
                }`
And the output was - `entered onResponse if` and nothing else.

Comment: Copy the print out from the log to the question so we can see what the response is!

Comment: Update your question with what you have changed and what the response in the log is

Answer (score 0):

Please get response like

try {

```
                JSONObject json;
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            if (json != null) {

                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("mainTags");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Sting name = c.getString("name");
                    Log.d("namee", name);


                }


            } else {
                // Log.d("Server Unreachable",
                // "Unable to Perform Your request.Server Is Unreachable! Please Try Later.");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```